# GWT composite widget

Tags: java, gwt, widget, composite

I try to build own GWT widget. I select the composite way of build it. But I have problem, the widget didn't see on screen. Here is the composite widget code:

```
public class LoginPanel extends Composite {

private static final String DEFAULT_STYLENAME = "LoginPanel";

private TextBox nameField;
private PasswordTextBox passField;
private Button loginButton;
private Label errorLbl;
private DecoratedPopupPanel decoratedPopupPanel;

public LoginPanel() {
    nameField = new TextBox();
    passField = new PasswordTextBox();
    loginButton = new Button("Login");
    loginButton.getElement().setId("loginButton");
    errorLbl = new Label();

    Grid grid = new Grid(4, 2);
    grid.setWidget(0,0, errorLbl);
    grid.setWidget(1,0, new Label("Name"));
    grid.setWidget(1,1, nameField);
    grid.setWidget(2,0, new Label("Password"));
    grid.setWidget(2,1, passField);
    grid.setWidget(3,1, loginButton);

    decoratedPopupPanel = new DecoratedPopupPanel();
    initWidget(decoratedPopupPanel);
    //decoratedPopupPanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    decoratedPopupPanel.setWidget(grid);
    //decoratedPopupPanel.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    decoratedPopupPanel.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
        public void setPosition(int i, int i1) {
            decoratedPopupPanel.setPopupPosition(Window.getClientWidth()/2, Window.getClientHeight()/2);
        }
    });
}
```

}

In entry class function `onModuleLoad()` I have this peace of code:

```
LoginPanel lp = new LoginPanel();
RootPanel.get().add(lp);
```

When I delete in `LoginPanel` class rows behind `initWidget()` function, then all is right, but widget is not centered. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should really consider using UIBinder, it's a much nicer way to construct widgets: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a `PopupPanel` can't be used as a 'normal' widget, because it won't be attached to a parent but it attaches itself to the dom to make guarantee it's on top. So using initWidget on a popup doesn't make sense.

To make this work you should put the LoginWidget in the PopupPanel instead of the other way around. You could make the PopupPanel a member field and add a method show to your LoginPanel that calls the show on the PopupPanel field.

If you don't want the login widget to float independent of a parent or context you're using the Login widget in, you shouldn't use a PopupPanel.

Comment: Or extend DecoratedPopupPanel instead of composite, use setWidget() instead of initWidget, and replace all of your current references to `decoratedPopupPanel` with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to call initWidget as the last thing. Otherwise all the processing of 'children' items doesn't have anything to work against.

Try that, and if that doesn't work, I'll try and give a better answer.

Comment: In documentation is this:

initWidget

protected void initWidget(Widget widget)
Sets the widget to be wrapped by the composite. The wrapped widget must be set before calling any Widget methods on this object, or adding it to a panel. This method may only be called once for a given composite.
Parameters:
widget - the widget to be wrapped.

Check here http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html#initWidget(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget)

I try this way, but widget wasn't centred.

Comment: The 'this object' means the composite, and not the wrapped widget. The wrapped widget needs to be constructed before being passed to initWidget.  I would assume that your widget appears when you do the initWidget last. Is that correct? The centering issue seems more like a CSS issue, then a result of the initWidget/composite.