# popuppanel show up beneath the widget

Tags: gwt, dom, uibinder

I am new to GWT and the web stuff.

I am working out my own project based on 
http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FCloudTasks-AppEngine%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fcloudtasks%2Fclient

I am trying to use popup/dialog. The popup and dialog always show behind the widget. I keep googling around and the most relevant I found is this 
http://groups.google.com/group/gwt-google-apis/browse_thread/thread/40db4fcbe10d2060 which does not provide any answer. Anyway, I have 3rd party library, bst-player 1.3, which uses flash. So I disabled it(later remove it too), the popup just won't come to the top! It is still hiding behind the widget.

I have learned that popuppanel/dialogpanel alikes [do not need to get added to another widget](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CG8QFjAJ&url=http://groups.google.com/group/mvp4g/browse_thread/thread/d7dfd91a31df5462&ei=SVaCT6r8O7K40QG6trn5Bw&usg=AFQjCNGYRiRnRkX5_CaOXgJmnclnZnGA3A). A different way of saying is that it is not a normal widget in a sense that it cannot attach to a parent but it attaches itself to the dom to guarantee being on top (from [GWT composite widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168917/gwt-composite-widget) )

I am at my wit end and I am here at SO ...

**UPDATE**

Here is my Popup class

```
public class PopUp {
    static PopupPanel simplePopup;

    public static void init() {
        simplePopup = new PopupPanel(true);
        simplePopup.hide();
        simplePopup.setVisible(false);

 //       DOM.setIntStyleAttribute(simplePopup.getElement(), "zIndex", 3);
    }

    public static void showpopupmsg(String msg, int left, int top) {
        if (simplePopup == null) {
            init();
        }
        if (msg != null && !msg.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            simplePopup.ensureDebugId("cwBasicPopup-simplePopup");
            simplePopup.setWidget(new HTML(msg));
            simplePopup.setVisible(true);
            simplePopup.setPopupPosition(left, top);
            simplePopup.setWidth("475px");  //575
            simplePopup.setGlassEnabled(true);
            simplePopup.show(); 
        }
    }

    public static void show(String message){
        if (simplePopup == null) {
            init();
        }
        simplePopup.setGlassEnabled(true);
        simplePopup.setTitle(message);
        simplePopup.center();
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling

```
tasksTable.doneColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<TaskProxy, Boolean>() {
  public void update(int index, TaskProxy task, Boolean value) {

      String msg = "Here is the popup. All the way underneath";
      Widget source = tasksTable;
      int left = source.getAbsoluteLeft() - 50;
      // source.getAbsoluteLeft() + 25;
      int top = source.getAbsoluteTop() - 25;
      PopUp.showpopupmsg(msg, left, top);       //Here is the calling method

    TaskRequest request = requestFactory.taskRequest();
    TaskProxy updatedTask = request.edit(task);
    updatedTask.setDone(value);
    request.updateTask(updatedTask).fire();

  }
});
```

Here is how the Popup is **beneath** the widget.
[image]

Comment: if you are going to downvote or close, please explain why.

Comment: Probably because you should show your code that's causing the problem, not just some general information about your project.

Comment: I have included the project in code.google.com which my project is based upon and there aren't much deviation from there.

Comment: Still impossible to help you. I have no idea what the problem is. You will not get any answers. Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: well, I have added more info as requested.

Comment: I tested your Popup code in GWT 2.4 and IE 9.0. It works great. It does not hide behind any widget. The problem could be with the widget that is coming over the popup. Can you provide the code for the 'Cloud Tasks' widget as well?

Comment: @Ganesh Kumar Thanks for the interest. Here is the code http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/src/com/cloudtasks/client/CloudTasksWidget.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem has been quite elusive since I am still new to the webapp, yet, I finally solve it myself. The culprit is the CSS. It is defining the z-index for the whole thing to quite high as seen in the following code line 1333.

http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/war/CloudTasks.css#1333

I have doubted about the z-index before and try it out with a paltry value 3 as seen in the commented out code segment of Popup class in question. I have to uncomment it and set it to 101.

```
DOM.setIntStyleAttribute(simplePopup.getElement(), "zIndex", 101);
```

I was , you know, #$%#@#$*.

Comment: "z-index"  in DOM.setIntStyleAttribute(simplePopup.getElement(), "zIndex", 101);

Answer (score 1):

z-index is only decides which widget should show on top.. 
the widget popup is under benath might be having z-index value high.

set the z-index for popup thru css (recomended) or DOM will work for you

Answer (score 0):

According to my feeling, using static methods of your "PopUp" object is a bit strange...
In that way, I think  things a relative to the top rather than caller object.

Maybe you could consider make your class 'Popup' extending 'popupanel'
and in your calling code, just make

```
new PopUp(msg,left,top).show() ;
```

Comment: nope. Just tried it changing from static to standard java class.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote my own solution for a popup panel that needs to be aligned with its caller. The solution consists out of an PopupPanel extension and a Button extension.

The button extension has an instance of the panel extension, and **the moment it is clicked** it gives its coordinates and width and height to its panel.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (optionsPanel.isShowing()) {
                    optionsPanel.hide();
                } else {
                    optionsPanel.setButtonBounds(new Bbox(
                            getAbsoluteLeft(), getAbsoluteTop(), getOffsetWidth(), getOffsetHeight()));
                    optionsPanel.show();
                }
            }
```

(The Bbox class is just a convenience class I could use for wrapping coordinates; write your own class or 4 methods for that matter)

The main work is then done in the **onLoad() override** of the PopupPanel, in which the coordinates of the button are used to position the panel;

```
    @Override
    protected void onLoad() {
        super.onLoad();
        if (null == bounds) {
            super.hide();
        } else {
            left = (int) bounds.getX();
            top = (int) bounds.getMaxY();
            setPopupPosition(left, top);
        }
    }
```

(bounds are the coordinates of the button; getMaxY() == bottom coordinate of button)